# Full Screen Netflix in Chrome causes my screen to goblank on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: netflix

thanks in advance.

This started 3 days ago and I can't for the life of me figure this out. When I start a video in Netflix in Chrome,it starts perfectly. Then, when I change to full screen, the image freezes for a moment, my screen then goes black and I can't get out without a restart.

It is in Chrome 44 64 bit and Ubuntu 14.10. I tried uninstalling  and reinstallingbut with no luck. ANy ideas?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1413710

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution which is working well for me till now -

posting it here -

I am using Chrome version -

> 40.0.2214.93

Faced the same problem. Tried this solution -

***disable the hardware acceleration settings***. in google chrome. For disabling hardware acceleration - 
go to the option "customize and control google chrome"
the gray area in upper right corner besides the option of Google input tools-
[image: Google Chrome Tool Bar]

Then click on settings from the drop down menu.
click on the blue option

> Show advanced settings...

check for the 6th category -

> System

and see if the box for using hardware acceleration is checked

[image: system]

if it is checked please uncheck it.

[image: hardware acceleration]

This has solved my problem. I hope it will work with you too.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I'm not sure how I missed your question when I was originally looking, but thanks!

Comment: Confirmed, fixed the issue